# Letter gets popped on using upper() method

Tags: python-3.x, string

```
s = '1 w 2 r 3gg'
s = " ".join(i.capitalize() for i in s.split(" "))
print(s) # prints '1 W 2 R 3Gg'
s = " ".join(i[0].upper() for i in s.split(" "))
print(s) # prints '1 W 2 R 3'
```

Edit: They're supposed to work differently, yes. Why did the 2 Gs get popped in the third LoC?

Comment: Oh, you changed the question. But still, it's obvious: `i[0]` selects the first character. Maybe that's a typo?

Comment: Yeah, I figured it's returning the first letter instead of the capitalized word. Thanks, wjandrea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `capitalize` capitalizes the first letter of a string.

The slicing you do in the second part selects **only** the first letter, and then capitalizes it:

```
i[0].upper()  # select first letter of a string and capitalize it
```

What you  still need to do is to take the rest of the string:

```
i[0].upper() + i[1:]
```

Or in total:

```
s = " ".join(i[0].upper() + i[1:] for i in s.split(" "))
```

There are probably cases which these aren't exactly the same, but this is the main point.